# ASP.NET MVC ModelState how to re-run validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to "re-run" validation of ModelState after I change model within my controller. Is this possible to do? Here is code example that explains it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
{
    model.Email = "defaultemail@world.com";

    // Email is required field and even though it's 
    // now valid ModelState.IsValid is false
    // how to re-run validation?
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // want to get here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Something else is probably making your model invalid.  Check the object to find out.

Comment: @Jonesy I'm checking the object and there is ModelError saying "The Email field is required.". I doubt that it is automatic - my property is not raising any kind of event that ModelState could handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `TryUpdateModel`

```
public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
{
    model.Email = "defaultemail@world.com";
    if (TryUpdateModel(model))
    {
       .... // model has been updated
```

[Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do it. In my case though I needed to also add ModelState.Clear() before calling TryUpdateModel.

Answer (score 17):

Clear ModelState and call TryValidateModel

In Your Case

```
 public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        model.Email = "defaultemail@world.com";
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(model);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Do something
```

Comment: This does not work if you have a more complex model, such as an array of objects on your ViewModel with their own data annotations/validations.